# Excel MS Office- months beetween dates

Tags: excel, outlook, ms-office, office365

I have a databes of dates with start date and end date.
I want to count only month beetween year 01/2005 and 01/2006.
e.g. from DB: Start 09/2004 end 05/2005, so I need only months from 01/2005 to 05/2005.
I tried some if and lookup Excel funkctions but didn't work.
Can somebody help?

https://ibb.co/jXJHYQ

Comment: Please post the data layout and the formula that you tried. For the least it would help understand better the problem.

Comment: Firstly I tried =datedif but it's only return month between two dates.
The problems is that  only some month including this data range, which only I need. As I said, End of date is in 09/2005 but range of date is from 01/2005 to 01/2006. So only 5 months should be return.

Comment: @A.S.H  I upload photo on top of question. Sorry for all mistakes, I'm new on Stack

Comment: Did you try `=COUNTIFS(I:I, ">="&M4, J:J, "<=" & M5)`? By the way you said your dates are in columns A and B. Now I see they are in columns I and J.

Comment: It also return 0 and as you can see on photo, it's not string but dafe form. The columns are different cuz I copy small part of them to show you the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a start date is on cell F10 and the end date is on cell F11, you can get the number of months by typing this into any cell:

"=(YEAR(F11)-YEAR(F10))*12+MONTH(F11)-MONTH(F10)"

Comment: Yeah I recive only a number of months from start to end. But some dates Starts before 2003 and ends before 2004 so I didnt need them. One months in the range of 2005-2006.